# Jquery dialog IE9 content not showing using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have dont a smalle web application for a client.
I have tested it in firefox, chrome, IE7, IE8 and IE9.

Now I cant get it to fail. Its working in every browser/version I have tested. Im not sure what build my client is sitting with but he said it was IE9.

The code is this:

```
function noticeBox(type, html, title) {
switch(type) {
    case 1:
    $('#notice_box').dialog({
        title: title,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        buttons: {
            'Ok': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });     
    break;
    case 2:
    $('#notice_box').dialog({
        title: title,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        buttons: {
            'Bekræft og bestil': function() {
                $('#form_products').submit();
            },
            'Annuller': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });     
    break;
    case 3:
    $('#notice_box').dialog({
        title: title,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        buttons: {
            'Luk': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }   
    });
    break;
}
alert(html);
$('#notice_box').html(html);
$('#notice_box').dialog('open'); }
```

Not a very generic function but thats what is failing at the moment. He says that when the dialog pop's there is no content in the dialog. He can see the buttons but is like there is no html in the dialog it self.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Btw he can active several dialogs and the result is the same in all of them. Dialogs without any content.

UPDATE2: An example how I use that function is this. When a client orders some products:

```
function order() {
var procuct_str = '';
var found_order = false;
$.each($('.order_input'), function(){
    var product_id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 0) {
        found_order = true;
        procuct_str = procuct_str+'<div class="float_left"><span class="bread_text">'+$('#description-'+product_id[1]).text()+'</span></div><div class="float_right"><span class="bread_text">'+$(this).val()+'</span></div><div class="clear"></div>';
    }
}); 

if(found_order == true) {
    procuct_str = '<div class="float_left"><b>Beskrivelse</b></div><div class="float_right"><b>Antal kasser</b></div><div class="clear"></div>'+procuct_str;

    noticeBox(2, procuct_str, 'Bekræftelse');
    var found_order = false;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `html` variable needs to be accessed within the scope of the function, unless you've declared it elsewhere. From the code you provided, `html` is a function argument, and outside the function it will always be 'undefined'.

Comment: It should be I use html in the function function noticeBox(type, html, title) { and when I use html its down at the bottom of the function $('#notice_box').html(html);

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

I used your function like this:

```
noticeBox(1, "<p>Hello</p>", "Test");
```

What is your client supplying for the html-argument? Some html could possibly mess it up. Or simply maybe your client left it out which would explain why nothing is showing.

Comment: The client dosent control the content the function is putting in... its dynamicly created based on how many products he is ordering. An example would be:

Comment: `<div class="float_left"><b>Beskrivelse</b></div><div class="float_right"><b>Antal kasser</b></div><div class="clear"></div><div class="float_left"><span class="bread_text">Baneguide</span></div><div class="float_right"><span class="bread_text">1</span></div><div class="clear"></div><div class="float_left"><span class="bread_text">Brevpapir A4 m. Fl kort, Vnr. 006</span></div><div class="float_right"><span class="bread_text">1</span></div><div class="clear"></div>`

Comment: Look at the main topic UPDATE 2. Might clarify it better

Comment: Hm okay. Why do you declare
var found_order = false;
in the end of your code, shouldn't it be found_order = false;
otherwise each time order runs it will open the dialog without content after found_order = true the first time.

Comment: procuct_str is empty, then this code is run:

procuct_str = '<div class="float_left"><b>Beskrivelse</b></div><div class="float_right"><b>Antal kasser</b></div><div class="clear"></div>'+procuct_str;

noticeBox(2, procuct_str, 'Bekræftelse');
var found_order = false;

Would give you an almost empty dialog. Is your customer seeing the "Beskrivelse" and "Antal Kasser"-texts? Or is the dialog completely empty?

Comment: Nicklas Erman you are right. Actually the line is not needed at that point. Its only there to make sure that dialog is only created if there is a product ordered. I was told that he was not able to see any of the text(as I recall) - thats what im confused about :) its a blank dialog he said. Might have to pay him a visit to see it for my self. At least ask him again if he can se some of the text...

Comment: I can now confirm that the client is not getting any text in the dialog besides the two buttons that show up fine.